# Flutter: Colors defined in multiple packages

Tags: android-studio, colors, duplicates, flutter

How would you circumvent this problem?

The name 'Colors' is defined in the libraries 'colors.dart' and 'v3.dart'.

**Conflicting packages:**

- import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
- import 'package:googleapis/calendar/v3.dart';

[image: Print Screen to MSPaint to Snipping Tool xd]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
import 'package:googleapis/calendar/v3.dart' as v3;

...

backgroundColor: v3.Colors.teal
```

If you don't need `Colors` from one of these two packages anyway, you can also use

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' hide Colors;
```

or explicitly show what you need from one library (hides all not explicitly shown)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' show StatefulWidget, StatelessWidget;
```